# How to make minibuffer not to show up "Matches (" in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, parentheses, minibuffer

When I was editting text in minibuffer ,I entered "(" and ")". Then minibuffer shows message like "Matches (" for a few seconds. I do not want this message showing up. How to make this message function off? I think show-paren-mode is enough for me to check paren in minibuffer.

Example of key sequence and minibuffer:

```
time| minibuffer
----+------------
0   | M-x
1   | M-x (
2   | M-x ()
3   | Matches (
4   | M-x ()
```

I'm using Emacs 24.3 on MacOSX.
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to report it as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it by adding this to your init file

```
(setq blink-matching-paren nil)
```